# Issues with Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-office

I am experiencing two issues with Word 2016.

1. After opening Word, it always hangs within several minutes
2. After setting the font type, and set as default, the normal.dotm file doesn't update and the settings are lost after restarting Word.

To resolve the above problems, I have tried to perform windows update, disable all the add-ins, and also used another new user account with different profile to login. I've even reinstalled office 2016, but to no avail.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: These are a few steps you could take : (1) Download the latest setup of Office 2016 online and install that. (2) Make sure the copy you run is not pirated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
After completely removing the office 2016 using o15-ctrremove.diagcab and reinstall it. It works normally.